# AWS keeps requesting new host key intermittently

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running and it seems like every couple months I am asked for a new host key.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
********************
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /c/Users/***/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /c/Users/***/.ssh/known_hosts:4
ECDSA host key for ***.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I know I can solve this but removing the offending line, which I have in the past multiple times. But I'm confused as to why this continues to happen on its own? I never change the instance. Secondly all my scripts I have pushed to the instance via `scp` are now gone, is there any way to prevent both of these incidents from occurring? I'm currently using an elastic IP as well.

Comment: Both of the things you described are symptoms of instances being replaced. Do you have an auto-scaling group or any process that would terminate and then rebuild the instance?

Comment: When you look at the instance in the EC2 console, how long does it say it's been running?

Comment: I do have auto-scaling enabled. But why would it terminate on its own? I was under the impression auto-scaling will rebuild automatically but what causes it to terminate?

Comment: @Parsifal hmm yes it says it was launched 7 hours ago

Comment: That's a completely different question ;-) Take a look at the events in your auto-scaling group.

Comment: I looked at the activity history and the event that started the rebuilding says `At 2020-05-11T13:09:13Z an instance was added in response to user request. Keeping the capacity at the new 1.` Is it possible there's a setting that tells it to do this intermittently?

Comment: There should be some other events at about the same time. Perhaps someone detached an instance from the ASG? Or temporarily reduced the desired instance count to force a restart?

Comment: You can also get more information from CloudTrail. For example, to see everything that touched an EC2 instance (and hopefully you're not constantly starting or stopping them, or there will be a lot of noise): https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/home#/events?ResourceType=AWS::EC2::Instance

Comment: I'm the only person that uses this, could it be because I have the maximum capacity set to 1? That's what I prefer, I don't want to incur additional charges.

Comment: @Parsifal and thank you I will look at that

Comment: @Parsifal Yea it just says theres a command that AWS ran called `TerminateInstanceInAutoScalingGroup` which was the last one. Not sure what that gets called im definitely not doing it lol

Comment: I'm afraid that the only solution is to start back-tracking to figure out what could have told the ASG to shut down the instance. Might there be some scaling policy that you tried out but then decided you didn't need?

Answer (score 2):

ssh-keygen -R [hostname-or-IP]

Try this